# iptables forward all but two ports (8000 and 22)

Tags: port, iptables, forwarding, dmz

**SOLVED:**

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1 --match multiport ! --dports 22,8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2
```

I found the multiport option!! This works as expected.

---

I am using 8000 for web and 22 for SSH. I am trying to forward all but those two ports. The following forwards all but port 8000

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1 ! --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2
```

I can forward all but a range with the following (all but 22 - 8000)

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1 ! --dport 22:8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2
```

Using the following does not work

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1 ! --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1 ! --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2
```

I tried commas as well. Also tried searching for a bit with no luck. How can I forward all but 22 and 8000?